# New object with reference member refers to previous object. Bug? UB?

Tags: c++, reference

I avoid using reference member variables but in looking at a possible use case noticed that these two ways to copy an object containing a reference produced different results:

```
struct Foo {
    int x{};
    int& rx = x;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1;       // foo1.rx properly refers to foo1.x
    Foo foo2=foo1;  // Compiles?? but foo2.rx refers to foo1.x, not foo2.rx
    //foo2=foo1;    // Expected behavior. It doesn't compile due to deleted assignment operator
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/tR8A_9)

Is it a bug that `Foo foo2=foo1;` compiles? If not is it correct for `foo2.rx` to refer to `foo1.x` ?

Is it possible to create a copy ctor that intializes the destination reference correctly, perhaps somehow with placement new,  w/o UB?

Comment: In the two cases you are invoking different operators. First one is calling the copy constructor. Second one is calling assignment operator.

Comment: @armagedescu, Thanks, I will correct the description

Comment: Apparently the reference `foo2.rx`  can only be initialized such that it refers to `foo1.x` so there is no way to get `foo2.rx` to refer to `foo2.x` with a ctor

Comment: Just provide your own copy-ctor, `Foo(Foo const& that) : x{that.x}, rx{x} { }`

Comment: @Eljay, yup, that works. I've been looking at this as a way to access a matrix class nRows, nCols without getters by making a const ref the the private values. I've been using a proxy class which works for 99% of my existing code. Occasional problems where the proxy doesn't automatically convert to an `int` and needs a cast. But it gets around the assignment operator problem of hacking the destination reference which is stuck with the original. Don't see anyway to do that w/o UB. I'll just use the proxy class.